# I am getting two different bugs

Tags: javascript

I am getting this error after running debugger failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

I am trying to insert a delete button into the DOM each time I add in a new to do item.

The delete button will be right next to the item created. hence why I am inserting it right into `<li></li>`

```
let view = {
 displayTodos: () => {
    let todoUl = document.querySelector('ul')
    todoUl.innerHTML = ''

 for (let i = 0; i < todoList.todos.length; i++) {
    let todoLi = document.createElement('li')
    todoLi.textContent = todoList.todos[i].todoText
    todoUl.appendChild(todoLi)
    let todo = todoList.todos[i]
    let todoTextCompleted = ''

    if (todo.completed === true) {
        todoTextCompleted = '✅' + todo.todoText 
        todoTextCompleted = '❌'  + todo.todoText 
    }
    debugger;
    todoLi.textContent = todoTextCompleted
    todoLi.appendChild(this.createDeleteButton)
    todoUl.appendChild(todoLi)
    }
 },
 createDeleteButton:() => {
    let deleteButton = document.createElement('button')
    deleteButton.textContent = 'DELETE '
    deleteButton.className = 'DeleteButton'
    return deleteButton
 }
}
```

Comment: right now you're trying to append a function. Instead, you need to call that function by adding parens after it: `todoLi.appendChild(this.createDeleteButton())`

Comment: I had it in the code, just forgot to paste it in here. It is still giving me the same error after inserting the correct code 
 ----->todoLi.appendChild(this.createDeleteButton())

Comment: And, if you move `createDeleteButton` on the top, below `let view {...}` ??

Comment: @KolaCaine did just that and this is the error I got   ---> this.createDeleteButton is not a function

Comment: Yes it's normal but @NicholasTower he suggest you to call function with parenthesis  :)

Comment: Yer I corrected my mistake by using his suggestion. Moved the method back down to it's original position and added in the parentheses. The code is now ---> todoLi.appendChild(this.createDeleteButton())

Still the same bug